How to remove all text inside brackets in sql server and return only text to the left of this
I have for example a string of text as below
John Smith (Boss:tom collins) (onleave) 

But I want to return only John Smith with no space after John Smith.
John Smith is stored inside an employee_name field
Is there a way to do this in sql server?
There can be more than one instance of the brackets
I tried using the below
left(A.[employee_name], CHARINDEX('(', A.[employee_name]) - 1)

but it returned following error in SSMS

Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
The statement has been terminated.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Always tag your SQL questions with sql and the specific DBMS (in this case sql-server). This will ensure your questions are seen by the largest audience.

Your issue is that when there are no ( in the employee_name field, CHARINDEX returns 0 and so the index passed to LEFT is invalid (-1). You need to check for the presence of ( first. For example:
select CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(', A.[employee_name]) > 0
            THEN TRIM(LEFT(A.[employee_name], CHARINDEX('(', A.[employee_name]) - 1))
            ELSE TRIM(A.[employee_name])
       END
from A

Demo on dbfiddle.uk
